# Closing REPL from Node - fire 'exit' event without typing

Tags: node.js, shell

I've been using [REPL](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) recently, but it looks as though there is no way to call the 'exit' listener without typing into the actual shell. Is there a way to call this from within the code?

```
var shell = require('repl').start();
shell.on('exit', function(){
    console.log("Done");
});
setTimeout(shell.exit, 180000); // This is pretty much what I want
```

Is this possible? The documentation for REPL is seemingly quite sparse - I'm not entirely sure if there's anything undocumented which might be useful here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the event listeners are actually available via `shell['_events'].exit()`. Seems to exit the shell just fine, and then execute the listener code.